# Jsoup Entire HTML Parsing issue

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup 1.7.3 and my HTML page is not getting loaded completely... Here is my code:

```
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/disponibilidade.aspx?versao=2.00&tipoConteudo=Skeuqr8PQBY=")
                      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36")
                      .maxBodySize(0)
                      .timeout(70000)
                      .get();
```

Even with maxBodySize set to 0, it still does not load the entire page... with timeout set to 0 as well...

Can someone help?

Joe

Comment: It loads from the start of `<html>` to the entire `</html>` for me. Some content is rendered with JavaScript and thus not possible to get with Jsoup. You'll need to use another library to execute the JavaScript.

Comment: define `not getting loaded completely` what part are you missing?

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine for me.

As mention the Daniel, some of the content is loaded with JS so you will need to use another library as Selenium or HTMLUnit

JSoup is an HTML Parser using CSS Selectors